# Всплывающая подсказка для JSpinner

Tags: java, swing

Я добавляю всплывающую подсказку для счетчика и хочу установить фиксированное местоположение для нее. Делаю это так:

```
sLength = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(4, 2, 24, 1)) {
    @Override
    public Point getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent e) {
        return new Point(0, -10);
    }
};
sLength.setToolTipText("Подсказка");
```

Однако, всплывающая подсказка всплывает там где мне бы хотелось, только если я навожу курсор точно на рамку спиннера. Если же навожу на его поле ввода, то локализация подсказки остается "по умолчанию".
Как можно препарировать JSpinner и заставить подсказку появляться там, где мне нужно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] - подсказка там, где я хочу ее видеть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] - подсказка не там, где мне нужно